# How to pass a web address in window.location.href as a parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using **window.location.href** to redirect a page in which i am sending website address as a parameter like,

```
var page_name='http://www.google.com';
window.location.href="edit-user-profile_2.php?uid="+userID+"&page_name="+page_name;
```

When i executed the script then its goes on a forbidden page.I am attaching snapshot.

[image]

I have also tried with ***encodeURI(var)***, but its not working,is there any function in java-script to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you seen the error. it is showing that you don't have the permission. check the permission to access this page.

Comment: Can u tell me how to check the permission of a page ?

Comment: check by answer. this will tell you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURI` only encodes characters that are not allowed in URIs, it doesn't touch characters which have special meaning in URIs. Use `encodeURIComponent` instead.

… that said, the URL in the screenshot doesn't have anything in it that looks like it would make sense to pass it a URL. Possibly you are trying to commit an XSS attack and the server is successfully defending itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing a `403 Forbidden` error when sending a user to the page, then the page itself may not be readable by the web server. Check the permissions of the page `edit-user-profile_2.php`.

Comment: Can u tell me how to check the permission of a page ?

Comment: You can use an FTP client and check, or SSH into the server and run `ls -l` on the directory with that file and see the permission settings.